# How to place two line of text in front of the sum sign?

Tags: equations, positioning

So I have this `\[ min\sum_{i=1}^{n} \]` which results in

[image]

What should I change to get this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for the short answer in advance. The `\min` command is already defined as a math operator and accepts arguments to be placed under. Notice the difference between the use in the text and the standalone equation use. (They are usually referred as `inline math` and `displayed math`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hi I want to use some numerical optimization method to solve the problem 
formulated by $\min_{S(t)} \sum_{i=1}^{n}$, but it looks terrible and my 
eyes hurt. So once again with much nicer,
\[
\min_{S(t)} \sum_{i=1}^{n}
\]
I still don't know what to sum up. That's some future work.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\underset` command with package `amsmath`

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\[ \underset{S(t)}{\min}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \]
```

Edit:
As percusse noted, you can use `\min_{S(t)}`.
You must load the `amsmath` package however for it to work.

`\underset` is more general and can support non-standard operators such as:

```
\[ \underset{S(t)}{\operatorname{arg~min}} \]
```

Comment: Why use `\underset` if `\min` is an operator that takes limits (see percusse's comment)?

Comment: I was asking myself the same question, just edited anyway

Comment: `\min_{S(t)}` doesn't require `amsmath`.

Comment: For limits under a "personal operator" use `\operatorname*{arg\,min}_{S(t)}`; no need for `\underset`.